# java - jQuery Grid Struts2 not displaying data and table

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

I want to display grid but when I click in the button to get info, nothing is displayed neither any grid nor any data. I make an ajax call in the "href" grid property ("ajaxLlenarTablaAssistance"):

```
<%@taglib prefix="sj"   uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sjg"  uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script>

<sjg:grid
        id          ="gridAssistance"                       gridModel   ="gridAssistance"
        href        ="ajaxLlenarTablaAssistance"            dataType    ="json"        
        caption     ="Detalle de Asistencia"                altRows     ="true"                             
        pager       ="true"                                 pagerInput  ="false"
        pagerButtons="true"                                 rowList     ="10,15,20,25,30"
        rowNum      ="10"                                   rownumbers  ="true"
        navigator   ="true"                                 viewrecords ="true"
        hidegrid    ="false"                                multiselect ="false"
        navigatorRefresh="false"                            navigatorSearch="false"             
        resizable   ="true"                                 

    >
                <sjg:gridColumn id="idProm" name="idProm"   title="ID PROMOVENDEDOR"        index="idProm"      sortable="false"    />
                <sjg:gridColumn id="name" name="name"   title="NOMBRE"      index="name"        sortable="false"    width="150" />
                <sjg:gridColumn id="puesto" name="puesto"   title="PUESTO"      index="puesto"      sortable="false"    width="100"/>
                <sjg:gridColumn id="idStore" name="idStore" title="ID TIENDA"       index="idStore"     sortable="false"    width="5"/>
                <sjg:gridColumn id="storeName" name="storeName" title="NOMBRE DE LA TIENDA"         index="storeName"       sortable="false"    width="150" />
                <sjg:gridColumn id="description" name="description" title="DESCRIPCIÓN"         index="description"     sortable="false"    width="100"/>
                <sjg:gridColumn id="week" name="week"   title="SEMANA"      index="week"        sortable="false"    width="50"/>
                <sjg:gridColumn id="date" name="date"   title="FECHA"       index="date"        sortable="false"    width="50"/>
                <sjg:gridColumn id="event" name="event" title="EVENTO"      index="event"       sortable="false"    width="50" />

                </sjg:grid>
```

My Java CODE has the annotation for the ajax reference. When i'm debugging nothing happens in this class:

```
@Actions( { @Action(value = "/ajaxLlenarTablaAssistance", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json") }) })                        
                    if(user != null){
                        if(user.equals(Constants.NOT_USER)){
                            request.getSession().setAttribute("code", Constants.NOT_AUTHENTICATE_CODE);
                            response.sendRedirect("managementError");
                            log.info(logPattern.buildPattern(methodName, idTransaction, "FAILURE.... DONT USER AUTHENTICATE...."));

                        }else{
                            obtenerTablaAssistance();
                            ordenarTablaAssistance();
                        }
                    } else {
                        request.getSession().setAttribute("code", Constants.NOT_AUTHENTICATE_CODE);
                        response.sendRedirect("managementError");
                        log.info(logPattern.buildPattern(methodName, idTransaction, "FAILURE.... DONT USER AUTHENTICATE...."));
                        finalize();
                    }

                    return SUCCESS;
                }
        private void ordenarTablaAssistance() {
                gridAssistance = new ArrayList<DetailProm>();
                try {
                    gridAssistance.clear();
                    if (listaAssistance != null) {
                        for (DetailProm temp : listaAssistance) {
                            //System.out.println("\n-N-> "+temp.getNombre());
                            gridAssistance.add(temp);
                        }
                        //Collections.sort(gridListaUsuarios, objComparator);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           

            }

            private ArrayList<DetailProm> gridAssistance;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private void obtenerTablaAssistance() {
            DetailReportPromVUtilities detailReportUtilities=new DetailReportPromVUtilities();
            listaAssistance = (List<DetailProm>) detailReportUtilities.getDetailProm("1223212112", date,nameProm.equals("") ? null : nameProm, idProm.equals("") ? null : idProm, puesto);//request.getSession().getAttribute("lstDetailProm");
            if (listaAssistance == null)
                records = total = 0;
            else {
                records = listaAssistance.size();
                total = (int) Math.ceil((double) records / (double) rows);
            }
        }
```

**No error is shown.**

This is the result and the code generated (FireBug). There are not info and the table is not displaying (I supose struts2/javascript generate the code for the table with class "scroll", the div with id "gridAssistance_pager" and the script tag below this, but it doesnt work):
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIZUV.jpg)

```
<div style=" margin-bottom:30px;">
    <br>                        
    <table id="gridAssistance" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    </table>
<div id="gridAssistance_pager"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
        jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.grid.struts2"+jQuery.struts2_jquery.minSuffix+".js");
        var options_gridAssistance = {};
        options_gridAssistance.frozen = false;
        var options_gridAssistance_colmodels = new Array();
        var options_gridAssistance_colnames = new Array();


    options_gridAssistance_colmodels_idProm = {};
    options_gridAssistance_colmodels_idProm.name = "idProm";
    options_gridAssistance_colmodels_idProm.jsonmap = "idProm";
    ...
    options_gridAssistance.resizable = true;    options_gridAssistance.resizableoptions = "{ }";    options_gridAssistance.jqueryaction = "grid";
        options_gridAssistance.id = "gridAssistance";

        jQuery.struts2_jquery_grid.bind(jQuery('#gridAssistance'),options_gridAssistance);
     });
    </script>

</div>
```

I have this jars in the build path:

- asm-3.3.jar
- asm-commons-3.3.jar
- asm-tree-3.3.jar
- freemarker-2.3.23.jar
- javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
- ognl-3.1.10.jar
- struts2-convention-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
- struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar
- struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar
- struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0.jar
- struts2-json-plugin-2.5.10.1.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.8.jar

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please post all relevant information, and a short code example (remove unneeded code)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @NorbertvanNobelen :D

Comment: Just saying it's not working doesn't help either, you should clarify the problem or error and post the related code to reproduce it.

Comment: @RomanC thanks for the recommendation :D

Comment: nothing is related, if you name a class then you should provide details where it's defined, without it it's impossible to answer, guessing sometimes wrong and your problem is not defined.

Comment: @RomanC Sorry it´s my first time D: I think i fix it! :)